# Correcting PowerShell script to show Disabled AD user account (not shared mailboxes) with Exchange mailbox and its size in MBytes?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, exchange-server

I am attempting to modify the script below so it is showing all Disabled AD user account with Exchange User mailbox still enabled (not Shared Mailbox).

Because the script below also returns Shared Mailboxes which is always created as disabled AD user account.

```
$Allusers = Get-ADUser -Filter {(enabled -eq $false)} -Properties homeMDB, mailNickName, mail, DisplayName, SamAccountName, Givenname, SurName | ?{ $_.homeMDB -ne $null }
$Allusers | Select-Object Givenname, Surname, DisplayName, Mail, MailNickName, SamAccountName, homeMDB | Export-Csv "C:\DisableduserMBX.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

It would be good if there is mailbox size as well in the column in MBytes.

Like in the below script:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |
  Get-MailboxStatistics |
  Select DisplayName,StorageLimitStatus, `
@{name="TotalItemSize (MB)"; expression={[math]::Round(($_.TotalItemSize.ToString().Split("(")[1].Split(" ")[0].Replace(",","")/1MB),2)}}, `
ItemCount |
  Sort "TotalItemSize (MB)" -Descending
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the MBYTES column, you can try this.
Note this uses the filter as provided by notjustme.

```
# for the sake of readability..
$filter = '(Enabled -eq $false) -and (msExchRecipientTypeDetails -ne 4) -and ("$null" -ne homeMDB)'
$properties = @('homeMDB', 'mailNickName', 'mail', 'DisplayName', 'SamAccountName', 'Givenname', 'SurName', 'ProxyAddresses')

$Allusers = (Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties  |
             ForEach-Object {
                $size = (Get-MailboxStatistics $_.SamAccountName).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()
                New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    homeMDB        = $_.homeMDB
                    mailNickName   = $_.mailNickName
                    mail           = $_.mail
                    ProxyAddresses = $_.ProxyAddresses -join '; '
                    DisplayName    = $_.DisplayName
                    SamAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
                    Givenname      = $_.Givenname
                    SurName        = $_.SurName
                    MBytes         = $size
                }
            }) | Sort-Object MBytes -Descending | Export-Csv "C:\DisableduserMBX.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

p.s. I've added the `ProxyAddresses` in there to be able to spot more alias emailaddresses.

p.s. 2 The `Identity` parameter for `Get-MailboxStatistics` can be one of:

- Name
- Display name
- Alias
- Distinguished name (DN)
- Canonical DN
- domain name\account name
- Email address
- GUID
- LegacyExchangeDN
- SamAccountName
- User ID or user principal name (UPN)

Answer (score 2):

`msExchRecipientTypeDetails` with the value of 4 denotes a shared mailbox. So to exclude these you could try changing your first line of code to the following and see if that gives you the desired output.

```
$Allusers = Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $false -and msExchRecipientTypeDetails -ne 4' -Properties homeMDB, mailNickName, mail, DisplayName, SamAccountName, Givenname, SurName | ?{ $_.homeMDB -ne $null }
```

You should also be able to include the homeMDB-bit in the filter directly;

```
$Allusers = Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $false -and msExchRecipientTypeDetails -ne 4 -and homeMDB -ne "$null"' -Properties homeMDB, mailNickName, mail, DisplayName, SamAccountName, Givenname, SurName
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply man, yes, it works. How about the Mailbox size in MBYTES column if that is possible.